# Troubleshooting Input alert or response in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to figure out how I get (a) an alert if user does not enter name, and (b) if user does enter a name a message is displayed "Hello (username),..."  I can get one or the other to work but not both.  Please advise.

```js
function checkingUserName() {
  var username = document.forms["register"]["username"].value;
  if (username == null || username == "")
    alert("Please enter> the username. Can’t be blank or empty !!!");
  return false;
}

function displayGreeting() {
  let usrname = document.getElementById('name1').value;
  document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = 'Hello ' + usrname + ', Welcome to Livewell page' + '<br> ' + 'You are officially a livewell member ' + usrname + '!';
}
```

I can get either function to work but not both.

Comment: How are you calling the functions? Please post a [mre]

Comment: `checkingUserName()` should return `true` if the name is OK. Then you can use a conditional before calling `displayGreeting()`.

Comment: Are  `document.forms["register"]["username"]` and `document.getElementById('name1')` the same element? Why not be consistent about how you access them?

Comment: Hi Barmar, thank you for responding.  I am fairly new to coding, and I was combining two examples of code in order to achieve what I have been practicing, hence the different id(s).  checkingUserName() and displayGreeting() work individually, but I cannot get the code to work as envisioned (alert if no input, or respond with hello user...).

Comment: You haven't answered -- how are you calling them? Are they in `onclick="checkingUserName(); displayGreeting();"`?

Comment: Edit the code snippet to show how you try to call both functions.

Comment: I am calling the alert with checkingUserName, and displayGreeting calls the hello message.

Comment: Don't describe it. Edit the question and show how you're doing it.

Comment: I know what the functions do. I keep asking you to show how you're calling them.